# Protect image path - PHP

Tags: php

Can i hide the real image path in a PHP page or use somekind of encryption [so viewers can't see the img src] ?
[
I've created a social network where user can share image or not !
The images are stored not in the database.]
]

i've seen some PHP page showing image with such data [though i'm posting a VB.NET code]

```
<data name="TrayIcon.Icon" type="System.Drawing.Icon, System.Drawing" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64">
 <value>
    AAABAAEAICD/AAAAAACoCAAAFgAAACgAAAAgAAAAQAAAAAEACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AABnZEsAjnMTAKmFFAC7lBsAdWEhABstOgAfNE0ARlt0AG6DmABziJsAN0NTAEpRVABWW1wAS0ktAElj
    iwBPbpEAQ1yBADlPcwBdc4gAPT9CAEY6EABUeaoAWIO4AGWCqQBdd5sAPVV7AHWPlQB3jZ8Ae5GjACs0
    PwAyJgUANTk6AFRphABbicEAZJLJAGGPxABjhroAdZClAHWIjgBne4wAZm9rABQWFQAwNDEANkpjAG2Y
    ................
 </value>
</data>
```

Comment: Storing in a non-public path is your better choice. Then, you can stream the image when a user requests it

Comment: It's not really possible to make it private. Once a user sees it, it's public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a PHP page which get some params, and handle it then.
Like a page http://www.yoursite.com/pic.php?token=xxxxxxxxxxxx, here you can handle the token, do some role authentication and session authentication, and then use header() function to push the pic to the browser so that people can download it but not seeing the pic path directly. Hope this help you.

Comment: But all you need to is save the picture locally for all that to be moot though

Comment: Users will see path to picture in this case.

Comment: after php process request http://www.yoursite.com/pic.php?token=xxxxxxxxxxxx, header("location: http://real_path.com/img.jpg"); User can see  http://real_path.com/img.jpg on address bar of browser

Answer (score 2):

What does it mean to hide the image src path? If you want the user's browser to display the image, surely they must access the data, right? So you have to tell them the address (unless you're embedding the image in the page in base64 or something, but this isn't better). But you don't control the user's browser... maybe it's storing the image in a file, as cache? Or maybe the user tailored it to do what they wanted?

One possible protection to make things harder would be to generate a unique link to the image which would only work for one request, the assumption being that if the user looks at the source code of the page and tries to use this link, then it's not valid anymore. But this is no absolute protection.

There is no sure way to do what you intend; you can only make it harder, but you only can hope that your users won't be smart enough to circumvent the protection, because there will always be a way.

Comment: good answer +1 :) But it would be appreciated if you can tell how to encode it in Base64  ?

Comment: The two images of the page http://a3nm.net/blog/fuel_efficiency.html are base64-encoded SVG images. (Yes, that's my blog--sorry for the self-promotion, but I only have this example in mind.) And no, this is probably not a recommended practice; it was convenient because of the backend used, but it's ugly and I'm not proud of it.

Comment: First public domain car image I could find.

Comment: @Sourav What do you mean? The example given is already in base64.

>"application/x-microsoft.net.object.bytearray.base64"

Comment: @Nick ODell i want to do this in PHP

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to build a system that totally protects your images from download, because of these attack vectors:

-Screenshots of the page

-Interception between the server and the client, (i.e. Wireshark)

-Looking in the browser cache

Comment: i know 1,3 are unstoppable ! :( But can i hide the img src path ?

Comment: @Sourav: There's really no point. Taking a screenshot is easy. Finding an `img`'s `src` is likely much more difficult for a user.